Mamba incompatible packages, but all may be installed
I am trying to install several python packages and in my environment.yml. I currently have
channels:
- conda-forge
- bioconda
- rdonnelly
- defaults

dependencies:
- python=3.10.0
- python_abi=3.10
...

However, when I run mamba env update -f environment.yml I get the following error:
Could not solve for environment specs                                                                                                 
The following packages are incompatible                                                                                               
└─ python 3.10.0**  is installable with the potential options                                                                         
   ├─ python 3.10.0, which can be installed;                                                                                          
   └─ python 3.10.0 would require                                                                                                     
      └─ python_abi 3.10.* *_cp310, which can be installed.   

I dont understand the problem since all can be installed according to the error above.
